# Trouble implementing a graph class in C++

Tags: c++, graph

I am relatively new to writing code in C++, and to practice, I've been implementing different data structures. I am currently struggling with how to implement a Graph. I am trying to implement a Directed graph, which has two abstract components: Edges and Nodes. Each edge has a value, start node and end node. Each Node has an int to identify it and a vector that contains the edges leaving it. A graph consists of a vector of nodes, which I made private so that the graph can only be changed through the methods I provide, however, the function header I wrote to access the vector of nodes is giving me an error I don't Understand. The error is

```
..\src\Graph.cpp:14:15: error: prototype for 'int& Graph<T>::getNodes()' does not match any in class 'Graph<T>'
 vector<Node>& Graph<T>::getNodes(){
               ^~~~~~~~
In file included from ..\src\Graph.cpp:5:0:
..\src\Graph.h:53:20: error: candidate is: std::vector<Graph<T>::Node>& Graph<T>::getNodes()
 std::vector<Node>& getNodes(){};
               ^~~~~~~~
```

If anyone has any advice about how to fix this error, or about a better way to design a graph I would appreciate the input.

```
/*
 * Graph.h
 *
 *
 */

#ifndef GRAPH_H_
#define GRAPH_H_

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

template <class T>
class Graph{
private:

 class Node;

std::vector<Node> N;


class Edge{
    T weight;
    Node* head;
    Node* tail;


};
class Node{
    int id;
    std::vector< Edge > adjList;

public:
    Node(const int& name):id(name), adjList(){};

    void addEdge(const int & name, T val){};

    void removeEdge(const int& name){};

    int& getID(){};

    std::vector< Edge >& getAdjList(){};


    int nodePresent(const int& name){};


};

public:

std::vector<Node>& getNodes(){};


void addEdge(const int& st1, int& st2, T weight);

void addNode(const int& name);

int nodeCount();


};






#endif /* GRAPH_H_ */
```

and my implementation of getNodes

```
template <class T>
vector<Node>& Graph<T>::getNodes(){
return this->N;
};
```

Comment: You don't see the `{};`, sticking out like a sore thumb, in your template declaration? ***Exactly*** at the line number from your compiler's error message? What do you think that does? What happens when you define an inline class method, and then proceed to define it again, outside of the class? You're declaring a bunch of template class methods that are empty. For starters, every self-respecting C++ compiler should be barking about returning no value from a non-void function. That should be the first clue that something is wrong. And then the second declaration would be a second clue.

Comment: `prototype for 'int& Graph::getNodes()' ` This is a different return type than either of the two definitions in the code shown. Did you declare it another time somewhere?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Are you asking help with your error, or are you asking help with designing a graph? You should have one question per question, especially when they are as orthogonal as this.

Comment: If there is nothing glaringly wrong with my implementation I was wondering what the error was. I am just trying to get used to writing in C++ and wanted to practice implementing graph algorithms so I wanted to design a class that I could use to do this.

Comment: I changed what Sam pointed out but my error remains the same. It says Node is not defined in my graph.cpp file and says the template arguement for vector<Node> & is invalid because Node was not defined in that scope.

Comment: That would be a completely different error than the one you showed, please ask one question at a time, make a new one for a new error and produce a [mcve] for each. In this case I can tell you though, that `Node` probably needs to be prefixed with `Graph::` because it is defined inside that classes scope.

Answer (score 1):

> Each edge has a value, start node and end node. Each Node has an int
>   to identify it and a vector that contains the edges leaving it.

This is redundant and therefore will cause you grief going forward.  If you store the nodes in the edges, you should not store the edges in the nodes.  And vice versa.

Comment: How does one find all connected nodes quickly, if there isn't this redundancy somewhere? Anyway, this doesn't seem to answer the question in any way, and should be a comment.

Comment: @hyde  Did you read the question?  It says: "If anyone has any advice about how to fix this error, or about a better way to design a graph I would appreciate the input."

Comment: Your answer doesn't really say how to better implement it, just how to not do it. It's a vague hint which is only applicable if one doesn't need to traverse graph node-by-node. Also, that part of OPs question seems unanswerable without knowing the requirements, as there are so many ways to implement a graph.